# Find the symmetry group of the following frieze pattern

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tfKJ.png)

I think it contains only translation symmetries, but I can not be sure.

Comment: There are more than just translation symmetries. Think: is there anywhere you could slot an axis of mirror symmetry in this pattern?

Comment: Oh, you are right. It contains also vertical reflection symmetry.